# doctrine validate Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: configuration, annotations, doctrine, symfony5, php-7.4

When running the command:

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

I've got an error:

`In AnnotationDriver.php line 179: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

I think it migth be a bug in annotations, but I can't find it. There are many entities in the project.

Dumping doctrine classess didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an issue in the doctrine package configuration. If yours is the same, go to the `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` and check mappings settings:

```
orm:
  mappings:
    App:
      is_bundle: false
      type: annotation
      dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src'
      prefix: 'App'
      alias: App
```

If you have any annotations outside the specified directory, correct `dir`.